# Add script to pandoc using the -A option

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to compile a markdown file to HTML using pandoc. I have already managed to convert the file and add a stylesheet to it, but I seem to fail to correctly add some Javascript. What I've got so far is the following command:

```
pandoc slides.md -o slides.html -s --section-divs -c slides.css -A slides.js
```

This already works pretty well, I am just bother by the fact that the `-A` flag seems to be able to import the `slides.js` file, and place it right before the closing body tag, but somehow it doesn't wrap the JS code using the `script` tag. Is there any way to do this? Or do I have to add the `script` tags in the `slides.js` file? That's something that would feel a bit weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the `-A` option is short for `--include-after-body`, from the MANUAL:

> Include contents of FILE, verbatim, at the end of the document body

so it's not specific to javascript files, that's why it behaves the way it does.

Depending on your use case, you can either use a [custom template](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates), or just use the `header-includes` [variable](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-set-by-pandoc) in the YAML metadata header:

```
---
header-includes: <script src="foo"></script>
---

my markdown document
```

and then run `pandoc --self-contained`

P.S. you may be interested in https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#producing-slide-shows-with-pandoc

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I know that pandoc can create slide shows this way, but I didn't really like the available options. And since I didn't think it is a lot of work to build something small on my own, I just did that. Put more thoughts about that in my blog, in case you are interested: https://danrot.github.io/2020/03/28/creating-highly-customizable-html-presentation-with-markdown-and-pandoc.html

Comment: sure, sometimes it's better to roll your own :-)

Comment: `--include-in-header` or `-H` behaves the same as `-A`, it is not specific to `js` and therefore does not work. The workaround with the `script` tag in the js file does not make sense and is weird as Daniel points out in his question.

Comment: `--standalone` also works alternative to `--self-contained`